# Getting current datetime on DotLiquid not working

Tags: shopify, liquid, azure-logic-apps, dotliquid

I am working on a liquid template. I want to get the current DateTime so used the following

```
{
    "DateCreated": {{ "now" | Date: "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss" }}
}
```

But resulted in the following

```
{
    "DateCreated": now
}
```

Getting the same result for "Now" also

Can anyone help me with this situation?
Is there any workaround ??

Thanks

Comment: I think you need to try like this one: `{{ "now" | date: "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M" }}`

Comment: @Onkar Thanks. But this works in shopify liquid but not working in DotLiquid even after I changed 'date' to 'Date'

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't have much expertise with dotliquid, I think you need to check with the compatibility section here, they mentioned about date also. https://github.com/dotliquid/dotliquid/wiki/DotLiquid-Syntax-Compatibility

Comment: Also check this one, someone claim into thread it works for him https://github.com/dotliquid/dotliquid/issues/45

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a number of tries, I got a solution for this

```
{
    "DateCreated": "{{ 'Now' | Date:'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffZ' }}",
}
```

This gave me the result that I expected on the logic app.